# How to set OTP retry limit in Azure AD B2C custom policy while using Azure-MFA to send OTP

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using Azure B2C custom policy for MFA, also using Azure-MFA to send code abd verify it. I would like to know how I can set Retry Limit while using it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow this Microsoft document to create a custom policy for set OTP retry limit in azure AD b2c application.

> **Attribute: NumCodeGenerationAttempts**
>
> The number of maximum code generation attempts per identifier. The default value is 10 if not specified.

MS document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile

Comment: What happens after this limit is reached? Can that identifier never be used to generate a code again? or is there a cooldown? if so how long is it and is it configurable anywhere?

Comment: Time in seconds until code expiration. Minimum: 60; Maximum: 1200; Default: 600. Every time a code is provided (same code using ReuseSameCode, or a new code), the code expiration is extended. This time is also used to set retry timeout (once max attempts are reached, user is locked out from attempting to obtain new codes until this time expires)

Comment: until unless the time of all OTP is not expire you can not generate a new otp. Suppose you generated first otp and within few sec then generated second otp . for second otp time will extend with previous one : total time for second otp is =600+time left of ist otp. it will so on your maximum opt generation and retry limit

Comment: If the second OTP is generated, is the first one still valid? Can user enter any of it within the first 600 sec?